# AWS synchronous method wrapping in Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, async-await

I am currently trying to use the AWS method [GetPreSignedURL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetPreSignedURL.htm) which doesn't not have a asynchronous alternative. Why would it not provide an asynchronous option?

As this makes an http request which could in theory take a long time, should this operation be be wrapped in a Task to mitigate this and make the application more performant? e.g

```
    public async Task<string> GetPreSignedURL(GetPreSignedUrlRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(awsClient.GetPreSignedURL())
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

This would then be called by something like

```
await GetPreSignedURL(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this makes an http request which could in theory take a long time

^ Here's the misunderstanding.

The HTTP request is not actually performed at this time. What this method does is it takes an HTTP URL (including parameters) and then signs it using your service's credentials. It then returns a *new* URL that is signed with your credentials, which you can pass elsewhere (e.g., return to your caller). At some point in the future, some other code will issue the actual request using that new URL.

Since your service credentials are already in-memory, and since signing is a CPU operation with no I/O, this operation is properly represented as a synchronous API.